# how can scroll delay for any section

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, scrollview, parallax

I am creating a parallax website and i need scroll delay when i scroll down. There is text animation, what i want. When i scroll down and text animated, scroll should delay until my text animation is not complete than other section should come up.

i am working for this website
http://client-acumenadagency.com/zois/

i need effect like this website 
http://www.lexusls.asia/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by this.

```
window.onscroll = function(event) {
    // called when the window is scrolled.
    var isAnimating = $("#idofanimatingtext").is(':animated');
    if (!isAnimating) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: but how can we make delay for any specific div? to using this function

Comment: instead of `window` use the corresponding div `$('#idOfDiv').onscroll`